# Error: Network Error in react-native

Tags: react-native, axios, react-native-ios

I'm getting the following error in my react-native ios application when I make api request.

I'm using axios for making api request.

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:546)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:381)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:485
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:181)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:306)
    at MessageQueue.js:108
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:269)
```

This is my code:

```
axios.get('http://myapi')
    .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: is android working?

Comment: Yes. Android is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to  do this [iOS App Transport Security and loading HTTP resources](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.28/docs/known-issues.html#ios-app-transport-security-and-loading-http-resources)

because iOS not allow http connection by default you need to enable it by setting App Transport Security Setings in info.plist

[image: App transport security]